I cannot use bold math for greek letters with MinionPro
% Start Preamble 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[minionint,mathlf]{MinionPro}
% \usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

A phase matrix is $\mathbf{\Phi}$, $\Phi$, $\bm{\Phi}$.

\end{document}

This produces the following:

I also do not know why \bm do not show anything.

Does \boldsymbol{\Phi} do anything useful?

Yes! Thank you!!
